# Measuring the amount

Tags: nouns

We usually say

> I bought 2 kilos of potatoes.

But can I say

> Potatoes were very cheap so I bought 2 kilos.
>
> I bought 2 kilo potatoes.

I think the last sentence is wrong. But I am not sure.

Comment: Your last sentence should read:

`I bought two kilo's of potatoes.`

But that is what you started with??

Comment: @MikeBrockington Better without the apostrophe in kilos.

Comment: @JeremyC  `Kilo` is an abreviation of Kilogram, which the apostrophe indicates.

Answer (score 2):

> Potatoes were very cheap so I bought 2 kilos.

Yes, that's perfectly ok and will be understood as 2 kilos [of potatoes].

> I bought 2 kilo potatoes

This is incorrect unless you are referring to individual potatoes which weigh 2 kilos each. (Now there's something I'd like to see!) (And in that case you'd better write 2-kilo potatoes for clarity.)

Comment: Or maybe it's "two kilo-potatoes"

Comment: I just want to point out that there's an implicit "of potatoes" at the end of the sentence "Potatoes were very cheap so I bought 2 kilos". It's left off for brevity and because potatoes were already specifically mentioned.

Comment: But ngram shows "2 kilo potatoes" is correct.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q="kilo%20potatoes"&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en